# Поиск слова в строке java

Tags: java

Ввести строку с клавиатуры. Из введенной строки выбрать все слова, начинающиеся на гласные буквы и заканчивающиеся на согласные. Вывести отобранные слова на консоль.

Добрый день, выше задание, не знаю как сделать, через сканер забил ввод строки, создал массивы с гласными буквами и согласными, но как дальше быть не знаю, может вообще не нужно было массивы создавать, ваше мнение?

```
System.out.println("Введите строку из слов"); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
String[] str = sc.nextLine().split(" "); 
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(str)); 
String [] glas = new String[] {"a", "i", "o", "u", "y", "e" }; 
String [] soglas = new String[] {"q", "w", "r", "t", "p", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"};
```

Comment: покажите свое решение

Comment: System.out.println("Введите строку из слов");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] str = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(str));
        String [] glas = new String[] {"a", "i", "o", "u", "y", "e" };
        String [] soglas = new String[] {"q", "w", "r", "t", "p", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"};

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в свой вопрос, чтобы легче было ознакомиться с вашим кодом

Comment: Ну как как. Берем в каждом слове первую букву, смотрим - гласная ли она, если да, то спрашиваем последнюю - согласная ли она. Если согласна, то на вывод.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так и задавайте вопросы , если что-то непонятно...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Solution {

    private static final Set<Character> VOWEL_SET = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'e'}));

    private static final Predicate<char[]> PREDICATE = chars -> isVowel(chars[0]) && !isVowel(chars[chars.length - 1]);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите строку из слов : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
        List<String> result = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                .filter(s -> PREDICATE.test(s.toCharArray()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());        
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return VOWEL_SET.contains(Character.toLowerCase(c));
    }

}
```

Comment: ``public static boolean isVowel(char c) {  return "AEIOUYaeiouy".indexOf(c) != -1;}`` и не нужен сет.

Comment: @Эникейщик можно и так, учитывая, что гласных букв очень мало, но идея ответа была в том, чтобы автор заодно попробовал разобраться и в функционале сета, все таки сет ищет не простым перебором элементов, а на больших объемах это очень влияет на производительность